# How to execute transaction with massive.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, massivejs

I'm trying to achieve a very simple thing:

```
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM table WHERE id = 1;
ROLLBACK;
```

Running this on the `postgres` database works perfectly. With `massive.js` it doesn't:

```
this.db.run(
   "START TRANSACTION",
   []
); 
setTimeout(() => {
   this.db.run(
       "DELETE FROM table WHERE id = $1"
       [1]
   );
}, 2000);
setTimeout(() => {
   this.db.run(
       "ROLLBACK;"
       []
   );
}, 4000);
```

It doesn't rollback the changes, just deletes from the database. `COMMIT` doesn't work as well. What's wrong?

Is there some way to dump queries order?

Comment: What is the point of such a transaction, as you end up exactly with nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Massive uses [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) underneath, which in turn supports transactions:

```
db.instance.tx(t => {
    // BEGIN has been executed
    return t.none('DELETE FROM table WHERE id = $1', [123])
        .then(() => {
            // Records have been deleted within the transaction

            throw new Error('Random error to fail the transaction');
            // = the same as returning Promise.reject(new Error('Random...'))
        });
})
    .catch(error => {
        // ROLLBACK has been executed, no records end up deleted.
        console.log(error);
    });
```

See also:

- [Accessing the Driver](https://github.com/dmfay/massive-js#accessing-the-driver)
- [Monitoring Queries](https://github.com/dmfay/massive-js/blob/master/docs/index.md#monitoring-queries)

> Is there some way to dump queries order?

[Monitoring Queries](https://github.com/dmfay/massive-js/blob/master/docs/index.md#monitoring-queries) shows you how to do it, or you can add event [query](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/global.html#event:query) handler within `db.driverConfig` object when initializing `massive`.